# Python: How to make a variable equal a message, and have the messages on the same line in console

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry if title is confusing. I am using python
code example:

```
a = print("_ ")

b = print("_ ")

c = print("_ ")

x = print("_ ")

y = print("_ ")

z = print("_ ")
```

I am trying to make these print on the same line, like this "_ _ _ _ _ _"
I have tried doing

```
sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
```

but it isnt working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print variable and string on same line in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153779/how-can-i-print-variable-and-string-on-same-line-in-python)

Comment: You're aware that this might get downvoted, because it's not a great question - so why ask it in that format?  There are a lot of answers already on stack overflow for this basic problem.  Have a look at questions for multiple variables print on the same line, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I have been looking and I haven't found the answer.

Comment: My duplicate suggestion is one.

Comment: What do you expect `a` to be in the above?  `print` will always return `None`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with this question, as indicated in the comments, and I think that the core of the question (How do I print stuff on the same line?) is answered elsewhere.

The main problem you're having here though is that, as Patrick said, you're assigning the variables the output of the `print` function, which doesn't return anything.  It puts the values of the objects you pass it into the text stream *file*.  If there's no file, it passes the value to `sys.stdout`, so there's nothing to capture into your variable.  You would need to do it in the format

`a = "_ "`

etc...

Then do

`print(a,b,c,d...)`

The documentation for the print function is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) - it might be worth your while taking in a tutorial or some time with the python docs themselves, as it's one of the first things covered in the tutorials - printing, variables and functions.